# Serverless nextjs will not cache js, css or woff in public directory

Tags: amazon-s3, next.js, amazon-cloudfront, serverless

First up i'm judging the cache hit or miss via chrome devtools, I'm in incognito mode, doing a hard refresh after each deploy.

I have a requirement to have a load of pre-generated CSS, Font, JS & HTML files in NextJS(serverless nextjs) /public folder.

No matter what I try, **I cannot get serverless nextjs/cloudfront to cache anything but images and html**. Things i've tried...

1. the [documented](https://serverless-nextjs.com/docs/publicdirectorycache/) way of doing it.
2. My version of the documented way:

```
  publicDirectoryCache:
      value: public, max-age=0, s-maxage=86400
      test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|txt|xml|css|js|woff)$/i
```

Now ALL of the assets are at public root, so then I thought let's check the meta on the s3 bucket using the above publicDirectoryCache, none of the .css, .js, .woff have the cache-control meta tag.

If I set it manually using the following it makes no difference.

```
aws s3 cp \
   s3://DEPLOY_BUCKET/ s3://DEPLOY_BUCKET/ \
   --cache-control 'max-age=86400, s-maxage=86400' \
   --recursive
```

I've been blinking at this for hours, any ideas?

Comment: Is CloudFront not returning the Cache-Control header? Or is the header being returned as expected, but it's not being respected by CloudFront (e.g., repeat requests to the same cache key / POP are not being served from CloudFront's cache)

Comment: Can we see the cloudfront behavior and cachePolicy?

Comment: Heya sorry I've been so slow to respond I've bee unwell, give me 24 hours and I'll restart the bounty and work through this with you guys - thanks for looking.